# Only Add searching criteria append to WHERE clause if value not empty

Tags: sql, vb.net

In web application, i can do like this to include the searching criteria if value not empty.

```
Dim sQuery as string = SELECT * FROM MERCHANT_CATEGORY WHERE 1=1 
If sCatDesc <> "" Then sQuery  &= "AND CAT_DESC LIKE '%' + @CAT_DESC + '%' "
```

In SQL query, how to do like the above? Below is the query i used

```
SELECT * FROM MERCHANT_CATEGORY WHERE 1=1
AND CAT_DESC LIKE  '%' + @CatDesc + '%'
```

If @CatDesc is an empty string value, and one of my record CAT_DESC is null, the result will show those records without null value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this form of query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MERCHANT_CATEGORY 
WHERE ((@CatDesc IS NULL) OR (CAT_DESC LIKE '%' + @CatDesc + '%'))
```

Note that you don't need the `1=1` any more.

Comment: i changed the sql to
SELECT * 
FROM MERCHANT_CATEGORY 
WHERE ((CAT_DESC IS NULL AND @CatDesc= '') OR (CAT_DESC LIKE '%' + @CatDesc + '%'))

then the null result also show when @CatDesc=''

Comment: Please edit your question with your updated code, and a more clear explanation of what output you want. I'm not sure what you're after now.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
select * from table 
where (CAT_DESC like '%'+@CATDESC+"%" and @CATDESC is not null  ) 
or 
(CAT_DESC is null or CAT_DESC="" and @CATDESC is null )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where cat_desc like '%' + isnull(@catdesc, '') + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we add the iif evaluation to the where clause?

For Eg

```
    Select * from table 
    where cat_desc like 
         (iif(@cat_desc is not null,"@cat_desc", "'*' or cat_desc is null")
```

This will throw an appropriate string value to the where clause.

ie. if @cat_desc is not null then it will pick up all matching records, if @cat_desc is null then it will evaluate the string --- cat_desc like '*' or cat_desc is null